# Использовать await с threading

Tags: python, aiogram, threading

у меня возникла проблема при использовании библиотеки threading. Мне нужно вывести функцию `Start` в отдельный поток.

```
@dp.message_handler(state=UpdateTime.UpdateTime)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text.isdigit():
        th = Thread(target= Start, args=(bot, message))
        th.start()      
        await state.finish()
            
    else:
        message.reply('Нужно ввести целое число. Время в секундах')
```

Функция `Start`:

```
async def Start(bot, message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'hello')
```

Ошибка:
`RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Start' was never awaited self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs) RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`